# chef attributes set to another attribute

Tags: chef-infra

In my attribute file i have

```
default['appid']['user'] = 'sysUserA'
```

Now I also want to set the same attribute to another one for a wrapper cookbook.
So I add another line so that with reference to first.

```
default['appid']['user'] = 'sysUserA'
default['service']['user'] = node['appid']['user']
```

The idea is to not update the same attribute at multiple locations. Is it the best way to do it, given that **default['appid']['user']** and **default['service']['user']**  definitely needs to be defined. Or this needs to be taken tot he recipe.

Thanks

Comment: Did your approach not work?

Comment: this should work for you :)

Comment: is it the best way if we have many wrapper cookbooks with multiple variables or should we move them on to the specific recipe from long term maintenance point of view.